# Connecting data in python to spreadsheets

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python 2.7.9. I want to present the data in my dictionary in a spreadsheet. How can I accomplish this? Note, the dictionary has over 15 different items inside.

Dictionary:

```
{'Leda Doggslife': '$13.99', 'Carson Busses': '$29.95', 'Derri Anne Connecticut': '$19.25', 'Bobbi Soks': '$5.68', 'Ben D. Rules': '$7.50', 'Patty Cakes': '$15.26', 'Ira Pent': '$16.27', 'Moe Tell': '$10.09', 'Ido Hoe': '$14.47', 'Ave Sectomy': '$50.85', 'Phil Meup': '$15.98', 'Al Fresco': '$8.49', 'Moe Dess': '$19.25', 'Sheila Takya': '$15.00', 'Earl E. Byrd': '$8.37', 'Rose Tattoo': '$114.07', 'Gary Shattire': '$14.26', 'Len Lease': '$11.11', 'Howie Kisses': '$15.86', 'Dan Druff': '$31.57'}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What specific part are you having trouble with? Did you google "python spreadsheet"?

Comment: yes, I looked into it. It showed my writing CSV files, but I couldn't get it to add a new row for every name and price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to write your dictionary in a Excel Spreadsheet?
In this case, you could use win32com library:

```
 import win32com.client
 xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
 xlApp.Visible = 0
 xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(my_filename)
 sht = xlBook.Worksheets(my_sheet)
 row = 1
 for element in dict.keys():
     sht.Cells(row, 1).Value = element
     sht.Cells(row, 2).Value = dict[element]
     row += 1
 xlBook.Save()
 xlBook.Close()
```

Note that this code will work just if the workbook already exists.
Otherwise:

```
 import win32com.client
 xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
 xlApp.Visible = 0
 xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
 sht = xlBook.Worksheets(my_sheet)
 row = 1
 for element in dict.keys():
     sht.Cells(row, 1).Value = element
     sht.Cells(row, 2).Value = dict[element]
     row += 1
 xlBook.SaveAs(mw_filename)
 xlBook.Close()
```

I hope it will be the right answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I will surely try this. However, if I change the dictionary and run the program again, will it update the existing spreadsheet and add the data, without deleting the previous data?

Comment: Data in Excel file will be overwritten. If you'd like to append data to existing data in your file, you could calculate the column length and start to write after that row. For example you can add this two code lines (while loop) between the row value initialisation and the for loop: while sht.Cells(row, 1): row+=1